# Jquery UI tabs Tabs at bottom not working properly

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery UI tabs its working fine if i keep tab title above the tabs now when i move tabs down its working fine too but if i add some ul li in contet section it stops working. as it takes as title of tabs here is my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabs">

    <div id="tabs-1">
      <ul> 
         <li> test content1</li> 
         <li> test content1</li>  
      </ul>
      <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
         <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
     </div>
     <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
      </div>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Kysf3/28/

Comment: See http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/ and search for `_getList()`

Comment: hello if i edit jquery library directly and add class there in get list function it works fine for me.how do i override that function?

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kysf3/32/)

If you switch around the `ul` element and move it to the top, everything should work fine:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>1.</p>
        <ul>  <li> hello world </li></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>2.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3">
        <p>3.</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kysf3/33/)

You can use CSS to move the position of the tabs to the bottom. See demo above.

[How to make jQuery UI tabs appear at the bottom of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027837)

Comment: yes i know its working on top but in my design tabs are at bottom.How do i set it?

Comment: You would have to use CSS to move the tabs to the bottom. The markup should remain unchanged. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027837