# jQuery UI tabs breaks when theres child list

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I'm guessing that jQuery gets confused by which list belongs to the tabs element. When I append a list to a slide, then destroy and re-apply the tabs, the tabs element breaks completely.

Click the 'DESTROY AND RESTART' tabs button and you'll see that the tabs are destroyed and re-applied without a problem. Then click 'ADD LIST TO FIRST SLIDE', then 'DESTROY AND RESTART' again and you can see that the tabs breaks completely.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGXBNz

```
'
```

I couldn't find a way to select the tabs navigation element directly. I think jQuery chooses the first list it finds and sets it as the tabs.
How can I prevent jQuery from breaking when it finds a different list first?

EDIT: Ran into this in the tabs docs although I have no clue how to implement. http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-_getList

FIXED IT:
Apparently jQuery UI lets you expand widgets, and so I used _getList to have the tabs only use nav with specific class.

```
$.widget( "custom.tabs", $.ui.tabs, {
    _getList: function() {
        var list = this.element.find( "ul.tabs-nav" );
        return list.length ? list.eq( 0 ) : this._super();
    }
});
```

Comment: One question I have is when you destroy and restart do you want the tabs to go back to how they were? Or are you wanting to retain what was in the body?

Comment: Basically I destroy the tab and then call the function that contains the tabs again. And that applies the same tabs options it had before it was destroyed. It retains what was in the body.

Comment: Could I ask, what exactly is the purpose of such a feature? I'm not trying to poke fun or anything, just trying to understand why this would be a requirement?

Comment: I'm setting options to the tabs element using data-attributes on the element itself. Calling refresh() doesn't get the new attribute values along with other stuff. So destroying the tab, then calling the function containing the tabs option along with the data-attribute values sets the newly changed data attribute options, Also when the tabs starts and it finds a child list before the atual nav list, it breaks on initiation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is the order of the list elements - your first set of UL is at the bottom. I assume this is because you wanted to position the tabs at the bottom. If that's the case, [check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027837/how-to-make-jquery-ui-tabs-appear-at-the-bottom-of-a-page) for moving the tabs to the bottom of the container using CSS to avoid this problem.

If you didn't do that on purpose and want tabs at the top, just move your container UL that has the tabs above the container with the details that you append to.

So basically it works when the HTML is structured like this instead.

```
<div class="tabs-element">
        <ul class="tabs-nav">
            <li><a href="#slider-1-tab-1">ONE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#slider-1-tab-2">TWO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#slider-1-tab-3">THREE</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="slider-1-tab-1">ONE</div>
            <div id="slider-1-tab-2">TWO</div>
            <div id="slider-1-tab-3">THREE</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I do want the tabs at the bottom and I was also looking for a solution that tackles the problem directly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem here is that the destroy method is operating on the wrong list, so you just have to be more specific about what gets destroyed. I came up with something that works by removing the list children before refreshing the tabs. Possibly not what you want, but it works.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVzxmb

HTML:

```
<button id="restart">DESTROY AND RESTART TABS</button>
<button id="add-list">ADD LIST TO FIRST SLIDE</button>
<hr/>

<div class="tabs-element">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="tab" id="slider-1-tab-1">ONE:</div>
            <div class="tab" id="slider-1-tab-2">TWO:</div>
            <div class="tab" id="slider-1-tab-3">THREE:</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="tabs-nav">
            <li><a href="#slider-1-tab-1">ONE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#slider-1-tab-2">TWO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#slider-1-tab-3">THREE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and the script:

```
$(".tabs-element").tabs();

$("#restart").on("click", function() {
    $(".tab").children().empty();
    $(".tabs-element").tabs();
});

$("#add-list").on("click", function() {
    $("#slider-1-tab-1").append("<ul><li>new list</li><li>new list</li><li>new list</li></ul>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I believe this is what you are looking for. In order to do what you are trying to do, you will need 3 methods

1. To save the contents of the tab
2. To clear the contents of the tab
3. To restore the contents of the tab once it has been destroyed and re-created.

The first two will need to be done before you destroy the tab. The last step is done once the tab is recreated. So your click handler now ends up looking like this:

```
$("#restart").on("click", function() 
{
   saveTabData();
   clearTabData();
   $(".tabs-element").tabs("destroy");
   $(".tabs-element").tabs();
   restoreTabData();
});
```

The three methods are:

```
var saveTabData  = function() {
 $(".container > div").each(function() { 
         tabData.push({
             tab_id: $(this).attr("id"),
             tab_val: $(this).html()
         });
    });
  };

var clearTabData = function() {
   $(".container > div").each(function() {
    $(this).html("");
   })
};

var restoreTabData = function() {
    $.each(tabData, function(key, value){
    $("#" + value.tab_id).html(value.tab_val);
  });
}
```

Here is the [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxeZZV)